Cuando ejecuto el siguiente código, si no introduzco un número, por ejemplo una "e" ya no se ejecuta bien el Do-While
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
// Programa que permita cargar n números enteros y luego nos informe cuántos valores fueron pares y cuántos impares.
class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int cantPar=0, cantImpar=0, numero=0;
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);
    String salir="No";
    BufferedReader keyboard = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        do{
            System.out.println("Introduce un número: ");
            try {  
                numero = teclado.nextInt();
                if (numero % 2 == 0) {          // número par
                    cantPar = cantPar + 1;
                } else {                    // impar
                    cantImpar = cantImpar + 1;
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {   
                    System.out.println("Debe ingresar obligatoriamente un número entero y no mayor de 2147483647.");
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
           }

            System.out.println("Deseas salir (Si/No)");
            salir= keyboard.readLine();
        } while (salir.equals("No"));
        System.out.println("Hay "+cantPar+" números pares y "+cantImpar+" números impares");
}

}

el problema lo tienes con el try-catch, puedes limpiar el buffer del Scanner dentro del bloque catch. Y cuidado con la introducción de datos manuales, trabaja las excepciones con equalsIgnoreCase para la comparación de la cadena no distinga entre mayúsculas y minúsculas.
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int cantPar = 0, cantImpar = 0, numero = 0;
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        String salir = "No";
        BufferedReader keyboard = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        
        do {
            System.out.println("Introduce un número: ");
            try {
                numero = teclado.nextInt();
                if (numero % 2 == 0) { // número par
                    cantPar = cantPar + 1;
                } else { // impar
                    cantImpar = cantImpar + 1;
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Debe ingresar obligatoriamente un número entero y no mayor de 2147483647.");
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                teclado.nextLine(); // Limpiar el buffer del Scanner
            }
            
            System.out.println("Deseas salir (Si/No)");
            salir = keyboard.readLine();
        } while (salir.equalsIgnoreCase("No"));
        
        System.out.println("Hay " + cantPar + " números pares y " + cantImpar + " números impares");
    }
}


También funciona utilizar esto para capturar el número:
numero = Integer.parseInt(teclado.next());
Gracias Ivan, por tu respuesta.

eso mismo el promblema esta en el trycatch
